# how to give two ng-repeat values in single column in ng-grid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I using table which contains 10 column. This table should have both horizontal and vertical header. First column under heading should merge two values one is color and another one value is string. The first column should be fixed and first column horizontal header should not contain any value (Empty Value). Can we achieve these functionalities by using ng-grid or we have to use some other plugin. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried but I couldn't able to fix the first column

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not clear, I suggest posting what you did so far.

Comment: Do you know how to upload image here

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?